# Change button color on showDatePicker

Tags: flutter, datepicker, themedata

I want to achieve the above design for my `showDatePicker`.

Right now the button color is white and **I want it to be pink**.

Is it possible?

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.white,
              onPrimary: Colors.black, // header text color
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this to achieve

```
    Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.pink,
        ),
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
          headerBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          headerForegroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      child: child!,
    );
```

Comment: It looks good, but now when I press the "edit" icon (edit as text), the text input is white instead of black. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: `datePickerTheme` is does not exist (maybe deprecated), and also the `headerBackgroundColor` and `headerForegroundColor` of the `timePickerTheme`